# initialState in configureStore doesn't return anything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mern, redux-toolkit

I build a MERN stack ecommerce using redux. In the part of cart components I add product to the cart and also to localStorage. When I refresh the page the items disappear from the page but it is still in localStorage and I can't find the problem.

This is my cart reducer code:

```js
import { ADD_TO_CART } from "../constants/cartConstants";

export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      const item = action.payload;
  
      const isItemExist = state.cartItems.find(
        (i) => i.product === item.product
      );

      if (isItemExist) {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: state.cartItems.forEach((i) =>
            i.product === isItemExist.product ? item : i
          ),
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
        };
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and this is my store initialState code:

```js
const initialState = {
  cart: {
    cartItems: localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
      : [],
  },
};

const store = configureStore(
  { reducer },
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

cart.jsx

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Cart.css";
import { CartItems } from "../";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { addItemsToCart } from "../../actions/cartActions";

const Cart = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { cartItems } = useSelector((state) => state.cart);

  const increaseQuantity = (id, quantity, stock) => {
    const newQty = quantity + 1;
    if (stock < quantity) {
      return;
    }
    dispatch(addItemsToCart(id, newQty));
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="cart__page">
        <div className="cart__header">
          <p>Product</p>
          <p>Quantity</p>
          <p>Subtotal</p>
        </div>

        {cartItems &&
          cartItems?.map((item) => (
            <div key={item?.product} className="cartContainer">
              <CartItems item={item} />
              <div className="cart__Input">
                <button>+</button>
                <input type="number" readOnly value={item?.quantity} />
                <button>-</button>
              </div>
              <p className="Cart__subtotal">
                {`$${item?.price * item?.quantity}`}
              </p>
            </div>
          ))
        }
```

I'm trying to use `useEffect` hook but the data come by redux doesn't save in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

The `configureStore` function takes only a single configuration object that takes `reducer`, `middleware`, `devTools`, ***`preloadedState`***, and `enhancers` properties.

See [`configureStore`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore).

It appears you are correctly accessing the persisted state from localStorage, but then not passing the initial state correctly to the store configurator.

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  cart: {
    cartItems: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems")) ?? [],
  },
};

const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  preloadedState: initialState,
});

export default store;
```

If your redux state persistence needs change or grow then I'd suggest taking a look at [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist). If you are already familiar with Redux then this is about a 5-15 minute integration the first time.

Comment: Bro Thank you so much it's work with me, I solve it using redux-persist .